# Button Control does not get/forward mouseDown/mouseUp/MouseMove messages

Tags: image, mfc, controls, drag, message

I have title-less MFC Dialog.
So it does not move if you drag it and you need to take care movements yourself.
I do this like this:

```
bool mbMousedown;
void MyDialog::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    mbMousedown = true;
    CDialogEx::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
void MyDialog::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    mbMousedown = false;
    CDialogEx::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
}

afx_msg LRESULT MyDialog::OnNcHitTest(CPoint point)
{
    CRect r;
    GetClientRect(&r);
    ClientToScreen(&r);
    if (r.PtInRect(point))
    {
        if (mbMousedown)
        {
            return HTCAPTION;
        }
    }
    return CDialogEx::OnNcHitTest(point);
}
```

It works - when i drag the dialog it moves.
But when i place button control on the dialog (yes i set notify to true) then the button control forward only click messages to the dialog but not mousedown/mouseup/mousemove.
It just does not have these handlers in class wizard.
So if user press the image inside the button control and drag the dialog like this then nothing happens since dialog did not get any messages from the button control.

I know i can solve this using activeX   - i do not want to add activeX.
I know i can derive from button box and do that - but really there is no easiest solution than that to get button to pass the notification or to make my dialog to move when user drag it with the picture control ? I have many button controls on the dialog  ...

Comment: Disabled controls do not intercept mouse messages. If you want your picture control to be transparent to mouse messages, disable the control.

Comment: Hi. Not sure how much that helps. I have dialog with no title. That dialog contains buttons and picture controls that acts like buttons. for simlicity lets say i have only buttons on the dialog. when user tries to drag the dialog then user most likely will hit the buttons since they cover 90% of the dialog space. If i disable the buttons user will not be able to click them ...

Comment: I have also edited the question - from picture to buttons. I have even tried to subclass the button and i pass mousedown/mouseup/NcHitTest
There in these subclassed functions i call GetParent()->SendMessage  and not my dialog does get these messages but i just do not know what to do with them - i tried almost everything ... so the new question is now that i do get notifications from the buttons to my dialog, how do i make dialog to move when user drag while mouse is on the buttons???  sending HTCAPTION from NcHitTest does not do that ...